# Email send through Postmark is not received by user

Tags: postmark

In our application email is send to users using postmark service, but user says that he dint receive any emails. Is there any way to know why these emails were not received by the end user?

I checked the Junk folder its not there in that and the From Email ID is also whitelisted. Only some of the emails are not received.